# Is there a way to distinguish between Tfs groups and Tfs Teams in the database?

Tags: sql-server, tfs

I am trying to figure out how to distinguish between Tfs groups and Tfs Teams in the database of an an onprem Tfs2015.Update3 (14.102.25423.0) server.

I have a Tfs team called “Team BAM” and a Tfs group called “TfsGroup”

[image]

I was hoping to find distinguishing attributes in the table [Tfs_Configuration].[dbo].[tbl_Group] when comparing these two, but alas, nothing. Maybe I am searching in the wrong spot, but I cannot seem to find repeatable differences when comparing more examples of groups and teams.

[image]

Any ideas how to distinguish between teams and groups in the database? For one, the Tfs web interface above sure knows how :- )
Many thanks!

Comment: The "Team" flag is an extended property of the identity. So I'm guessing this is stored in a different table that is linked to the group through the Group ID. See also: https://blog.jessehouwing.nl/2013/01/convert-tfs-2010-security-group-to-2012.html

Comment: I don't have a TFS database at hand to look up the exact table.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Jesse! I am fumbling around with the following query,  trying to come up with a possible link to the extended table, but no luck yet.

`SELECT *
FROM [Tfs_Configuration].[INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS]
WHERE column_name like '%id%'
and TABLE_SCHEMA ='dbo'`

If you do manage to find the table name at some stage, it would be much appreciated - and spare me more grey hair :-)

Answer (score 0):

The following query could list all teams:

```
SELECT map.[TeamId]
      ,map.[ProjectId]
      ,proj.[ProjectNodeName] AS [Team Project Name]
      ,ado.[SamAccountName] AS [Team Name]
  FROM [Tfs_DefaultCollection].[dbo].[tbl_TempTeamProjectMapping] map
  JOIN [Tfs_Warehouse].[dbo].[DimTeamProject] proj ON map.[ProjectId] = proj.[ProjectNodeGUID]
  JOIN [Tfs_DefaultCollection].[dbo].[ADObjects] ado ON map.[TeamId] = ado.[TeamFoundationId]
```

Comment: Thanx for the suggestion Cece! Unfortunately I still see a mix of Teams and Groups in the results of the query. 
Groups like Readers , Contributors and Project Valid Users still pops up in the result set. In the Tfs web interface these are listed as Tfs groups and not Tfs Teams.

Comment: Do you run this query in SSMS? I only see Teams in the returned result, no groups.

Comment: Yes, on SSMS 2012. It does skip certain groups though.
I get the idea that the query only returns groups that are actively being used.

Comment: You may consider using [TFS REST api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/core/teams/get%20all%20teams) instead of querying in database to get a list of teams: `GET http://tfs:8080/tfs/_apis/teams?api-version=4.1-preview.2`.